# Trying to change default Jenkins port on a Docker container

Tags: docker, jenkins, port, devops

As part of a school challenge I need to run a Jenkins environment using Docker on port 7070:9090.

I'm trying to change the default access port for Jenkins (8080) on a Docker container unsuccessfully.

Here's my code:

```
version: '3'

services:
  jenkins:
    container_name: jenkins
    image: jenkins-image
    ports:
        - "7070:8080"

    volumes:
        - "jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home"
        - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
```

I managed to change the localhost to **7070**, but not the default access port from **8080**.

All the tutorials I've found online only explain how to change the localhost.

Any advice on how to change the port **8080** and still manage to have Jenkins running?

Answer (score 0):

Access port is related with Docker instead of Jenkins. The syntax should be like this `HOST:CONTAINER` if the Jenkins is running at 7070 in your container following code needs to work for you.

```
version: '3'

services:
  jenkins:
    container_name: jenkins
    image: jenkins-image
    ports:
        - "8080:7070"

    volumes:
        - "jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home"
        - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.

Jenkins is currently running at 8080 as that is the default setting. How can I change it to 7070 so it runs with the code you provided?

Comment: My Jenkins is currently running on port 8080, so the code you provided will not work. How can I change the Jenkins default port? That's my question.